# error while parsing json object from url

Tags: android, json, parsing, url

i posted a question today about how to parse an php url that contain json objects here:

[How to parse JSON object from PHP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592006/how-to-parse-json-object-from-php-url)

But now i changed the url hoping it become easier to parse that url but still cant do it.

So when i parse a json object from url (.com) the application force stop and in LogCat error was :

```
10-25 22:44:25.065: E/JSON Parser(22241): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

However the code is working for other url.

Answer (score 0):

The URL contails html tag and not JSON string! It may appear to be json string in browser. Please remove html tags (use basic editor) and try again :)

Comment: my url is depends on a website that i have been taken the data and convert it to json using php,so how can i remove the html tag from it?

Comment: You could use a HTML DOM parser, extract the JSON string and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Could value starting with "<HTML><HEAD> " indicate application error? or page not found maybe?

Try inspecting (Debuger, or sysout) what value you are getting.

Comment: The reason is the html and header tags in the url ( not a json object)